# How to append results of 2 SQL procedures from C# into a single CSV file?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I have 2 procedures in SQL and their results should be dumped as a CSV file from C#. I’m able to get the results of 1 procedure , but I’m clueless as to how to go about adding the results from the 2nd procedure.

Procedure 1. GetCSVData

Procedure 2 . GetHeader

The below C# code successfully gets data into CSV from procedure 1 ('GetCSVData'). 
Please help me in integrating the data from Procedure2 (“GetHeader”) into ‘GetCSVData’ and write it to the same CSV file.

My C# code:

```
public string GetCSVData(string SId, string TotalRow)
{       try
    {
        Sql v = new Sql("Block_Rpt_CSV");
        v.Add("SId",SId);
        v.Add("TotalRow",TotalRow);
        v.Run();

        DataTable dt=new DataTable(); 
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Columns.Add("a", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("b", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("c", typeof(String));

        foreach (System.Data.DataRow item in v.Results.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item.GetString("Name"),item.GetString("Id"),
            item.GetString("Class")

        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();

        string csvData = DataTableToCSVFile(dt, SId, TotalRow);

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();

        string filename = "CsvView.csv";
        response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\";");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", csvData.Length.ToString());
        response.Write(csvData);
        response.Flush();           
        response.End();         

        AjaxBuilder r = new AjaxBuilder();
        r.Add("GetCSVData", "Success");
        return r.ToString();
    }
   catch (Exception e)
    {
        AjaxBuilder r = new AjaxBuilder();
        r.Add("GetCSVData", "Failed");
        r.Add("Exception_Message", e.Message);
        r.Add("Exception_StackTrace", e.StackTrace);
        return r.ToString();
    }

}
```

@Harvey : Sorry I missed seeing your post until now. Thanks for the code. However I've been struggling with this before I saw your's. Can you please take a look and at my code and see if I can get it to work? Else I'll use your code. As of now all my 20 columns heads are displayed in my CSV and obviously the data in each column does not match.

```
private string DataTableToCSVFile(DataTable dt, string SId, string TotalRow)
{       DataTable dtExcel = dt;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("CSV Data");
    sb.Append("\n");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dtExcel.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append(column.ColumnName + ",");
   }
    sb.Append("\n");
    foreach (DataRow row in dtExcel.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
sb.Append(row[i].ToString() + ",");
    }
        sb.Append("\n");
    }
return sb.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: You are using `foreach` for your columns. That will run for all the columns in the datatable and not only for first 7 cols like you want. So you will have to use `for` everywhere for looping so that you can specify the number of times that loop should run.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `DataTable` object as global and then use that same object in both the functions.

Run whichever you want first and insert the columns and records into id. And then, run the second one and insert the columns and records into it accordingly.

You can also use two separate `DataTable` objects for each function and then merge them after you have received results in both.

Also, make sure you write the actual CSV generation code at the end afterwards when both your functions are called.

**UPDATE :**

Here's how you can write your datatable values on a CSV file :

```
string csvPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("pathToCSV.csv");
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(csvPath, false);
if (dtDataTablesList.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            //First we will write the headers.
                            int iColCount = dtDataTablesList.Columns.Count;

                            for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                            {
                                sw.Write(dtDataTablesList.Columns[i]);
                                if (i < iColCount - 1)
                                {
                                    sw.Write(",");
                                }
                            }
                            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                            // Now write all the rows.
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dtDataTablesList.Rows)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                                {
                                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                                    {
                                        sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                                    }
                                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                                    {
                                        sw.Write(",");
                                    }
                                }
                                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                            }
                        }
```

Now here, since you want to split some columns and write them first and then the others, you will have to modify the `for` condition a bit here and I think that should be fine with you.

Hope this gives an idea of how to progress with this.

Comment: Thanks for the lead! My code is a little elaborate, will try your suggestions and update.

Comment: @Harvey- finally I have entire data of both the procedures in my CSV. My Datatable has about 20 columns (Combined with both the procedures). I need the 1st 7 columns data (with headings )to be displayed in 1 chunk of the csv file and the rest 13 columns data(with their headings) to be displayed under the 1st chunk of table. Is there a way I could do this?. Once again thanks for the lead!

Comment: @aruna - Check my update in the answer. That should give you an idea of how to progress with this.

Comment: can you please check my update on the question. Thanks

Comment: Hey aruna ! Glad that you got it through. Did you spent the whole week on this ? I hope not. :)

Comment: haha.. no .. just a day :) . I haven't got enough reputations to Vote u up, so thought I'll at least acknowledge :). Somehow I don't get notifications from stackoverflow to my email. I'll have to come back to the posted questions to see if I've got any solutions :(

Comment: Btw, are you from India ? Which location ?